# Оператор присваивания работает некорректно, выводит пустой объект. В чём может быть ошибка?

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <ctime>

class Matrix {
    int **ptr = nullptr;
    int x = NULL, y = NULL;
public:
    Matrix() = default;
    Matrix(int i, int j) :x(i), y(j)
    {
        ptr = new int*[x];
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
            ptr[i] = new int[y];
    }
    Matrix(int i) :Matrix(i, i) {}
    Matrix(const Matrix &ob) : x(ob.x), y(ob.y)
    {
        //выделяем память для копии.
        ptr = new int*[ob.x];               
        for (int i = 0; i < ob.x; i++)
            ptr[i] = new int[ob.y];

        //копируем.
        for (int i = 0; i < ob.x; i++)
            for (int j = 0; j < ob.y; j++)
                ptr[i][j] = ob.ptr[i][j];
    }
    Matrix operator=(Matrix rhs);
    ~Matrix();

    void fill();
    void show();    
};

Matrix Matrix::operator=(Matrix rhs)
{   
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            ptr[i][j] = rhs.ptr[i][j];

    return *this;
}

Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
        delete[] ptr[i];
    delete[] ptr;
}

void Matrix::fill()
{
    std::srand(std::time(NULL));
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
            ptr[i][j] = rand() % 10;
    }
}

void Matrix::show()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < y; j++) {
            std::cout << ptr[i][j] << ' ';
        } std::cout << std::endl;
    } std::cout << std::endl;
}

int main()
{   
    Matrix A(2), B;

    A.fill();
    A.show();

    B = A;

    std::cout << std::endl;
    B.show();

    return 0;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Матрица `B` создается конструктором по умолчанию, т.е. у нее нулевой указатель, и `x` и `y` равны нулю. Т.е. в операторе присваивания

```
for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    for (int j = 0; j < y; j++)
        ptr[i][j] = rhs.ptr[i][j];
```

по этой причине ничего не делается (и хорошо, потому что `ptr` у вас нулевой).

Вот вы ничего и не получаете :)

Но у вас еще есть если не ошибки, то несуразности...

Например, почему оператор присваивания получает копию присваиваемой матрицы? Это имело бы смысл при такой его реализации:

```
{
    swap(x,rhs.x);
    swap(y,rhs.y);
    swap(ptr,rhs.ptr);
}
```

И еще - зачем он возвращает копию вашей матрицы?

`NULL` используется для указателей (вернее, `nullptr`), так что использовать это значение вместо нуля для инициализации значений `int` - очень мягко говоря, нелепо.

Comment: Хорошо, буду думать, Мне педагог говорил что переменные лучше присваивать NULL, а указателям nullptr

Answer (score 0):

Нужно правильно определить этот копирующий оператор присваивания. Его определение может выглядеть следующим образом

```
Matrix & Matrix::operator =( const Matrix &rhs )
{   
    if ( this != &rhs )
    {
        int **tmp = new int* [rhs.x];
        for ( int i = 0; i < rhs.x; i++ ) tmp[i] = new int[rhs.y];

        if ( ptr != nullptr )
        { 
            for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++ ) delete [] ptr[i];
        }
        delete [] ptr;

        x = rhs.x;
        y = rhs.y;

        ptr = tmp;

        for ( int i = 0; i < x; i++ )
        {
            for ( int j = 0; j < y; j++ ) ptr[i][j] = rhs.ptr[i][j];
        }
    }

    return *this;
}
```

Желательно удаление и создание массивов, адресуемых членом данных класса `ptr` поместить в отдельные функции, чтобы соответствующий код не дублировался, так как он используется не только в одном копирующим оператором присваивания.

Также вы могли бы написать перемещающий конструктор и перемещающий оператор приcваивания.

Обратите внимание, что деструктор написан некорректно, так как в общем случае `ptfr` может быть равен `nullptr`. Правильно будет написать деструктор следующим образом

```
Matrix::~Matrix()
{
    if ( ptr !+ nullptr )
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < x; i++) delete[] ptr[i];
    }

   delete[] ptr;
}
```

Comment: Вы удаляете а потом заново выделяете память для объекта, но я выделял память в конструкторе копии. Или в таком виде конструктор копии не нужен?

Comment: @Ilya Конструктор копии используется при создании нового объекта. А копирующий оператор присваивания используется для уже созданного объекта, который уже имеет инициализированные члены данных.

Comment: @Ilya Я же вам показал, как можно красиво написать присваивание - в 3(!) строчки. Посмотрите еще раз - при передаче по значению вы УЖЕ скопировали матрицу. Затем просто обмениваете ее поля - в 3 строки, а удалением вашего старого объекта займется деструктор копии. И не надо заново писать выделение памяти и прочие телодвижения, если они уже есть в конструкторе копирования!

Comment: @Ilya Посмотрите тут - http://ideone.com/GjqQ95 - вот вам все присваивание, и все работает :) Кстати, корректно отработает даже в случае, если `&rhs == this`.

Comment: @Ilya Я внес некоторые изменения в определение оператора, так как в общем случае указатель ptr может быть равен nullptr, а потому нельзя удалять элементы ptr[i]

Comment: @Harry Для простоты можно создать функцию с использованием ссылочных параметров, как вы и показали. Спасибо за помощь.

Comment: @Ilya На самом деле это не отменяет в общем случае необходимости создать вам копирующий оператор присваивания.  Вам в любом случае следует создать его аналогичным образом, как я показал. Ваша программа может работать без перемещающего оператора присваивания, но она не будет работать без копирующего оператора присваивания.:)

Comment: @Vlad from Moscow благодарю за помощь и понимание